# practical usefulness of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

A man in the street may ask: "What is the practical usefulness of polynomials of  degree higher than 3, and of determining their roots?"
I would reply that polynomials of high degree can be used as good approximations of other functions (continuous, or by Taylor series).
They also appear in other technical contexts, like the computation of eigenvalues of matrices.
But i am not satisfied with these explanations.
So what are some other cases exhibiting the practical usefulness of polynomials?

Comment: interest on loans - the APR is often the solution to a polynomial

Comment: Polynomials arise by *composing* addition and multiplication operations, So choose any "useful" applications of addition and multiplication where composition has natural meaning.